# How to connect jaspersoft studio to intelliJ IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, jasper-reports

Installation & Usage
Install from Marketplace
Open Settings > Plugins > Marketplace in your Intellij Idea IDE, search for Jasper Report Support and install the plugin.

Build from source
Clone the repository and run buildPlugin gradle task in project root. After that plugin jar file will be generated at <PROJECT_ROOT>/build/libs directory

1 - git clone https://github.com/chathurabuddi/intellij-jasper-report-support.git
2 - cd intellij-jasper-report-support
3 - gradle buildPlugin

I have tried so many times this method but unable to connect my jaspersoft studio report to my intelliJ IDE???

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: No, I am not able to follow the second step, that is, building from source cloneand running buildPlugin in  project root